# How To Block Chrome Window Popup in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Selenium-Python script for performing some automation tests on website. The script repeatedly opens some new tabs performs some work on the opened window and closes it.

Issue I'm facing is that whenever a new tab is opened my chrome window pops up from Minimize state to maximize. I want it to do all the task in background without interuppting.

Ps: Headless version is not applicable for my scenario.

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options,executable_path="chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://xyx.org/#/login") #Login manually to a website.
while 1:
    #some stuff here 
    main_window = driver.current_window_handle
    driver.execute_script("window.open();")
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
    driver.get("some link here ")
    #doing some work here
    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to.window(main_window)
```

If I minimize the chrome window manually then whenever the `driver.execute_script("window.open();")` is executed it automatically maximizes the chrome window. I want it to just keep remain minimized and do the work.

Comment: So you want your window is maximize at the first place or you want to make the window completely run in background. I'm not fully understand your problem yet. Can you provide some code for better visualize.

Comment: I have updated with a piece of code block to make somehow clear of what the problem is.

Comment: What happen when you try [options.headless = True]. Are the main window in headless mode and the second is pop up or both of them appear on screen ?

Comment: I have to pass bot check at login page. So cannot use headless mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fixed solution, using two driver instead of one. Driver one to login and driver two to do the work on the window with headless mode.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver

options = Options()
options.headless = True

driver_one = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/chromedriver')
driver_one.maximize_window()
driver_one.get("https://xyx.org/#/login") #Login manually to a website.

while 1:
  #some stuff here 
  driver_two = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/chromedriver',
    options=options)

  link = "https://www.google.com"
  driver_two.get("some link here ")
  #doing some work here
  driver_two.close()
```

Comment: It's just opening a new window. The issue is still the same. Thanks for your helo though :)

Comment: Have you solve it yet ? Check my edited solution. You two driver instead of one. The second one will run in headless mode so it will not interupt. Sorry for previous solution. I kind of miss read your question :))).